# Cannot connect to a local network server in Visual Studio Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin in Visual Studio Community ;
I'm trying to connect to a remote database without success.

Tried WCF, REST, HttpRequest - none can connect to the remote server/service.
In a "New Console Application", however, everything works fine.
Also made "new Android project", it cannot connect to the service/server, either.

The following code works in a Console Application but cannot connect in Xamarin Mono (Visual studio):

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"http://192.168.16.100/RestService/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/12"));
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "GET";

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
    }

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Response Body: \r\n {0}", content);
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Is it local service on IIS?

Comment: Yes is a local, but anyway I tried with a link from internet and is work in Console Application but in Xamarin doesn't work ; this link is just a link to internet :  var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/RxTerms/rxcui/{0}/allinfo", "198440"));  In Xamarin doesn't work ;  I don't understand why ?? I have to pay some certified ? or sometthing ??

Comment: What does host `http://192.168.16.100/`?

Comment: From my Point of view Visual Studio Xamarin Android is not able to connect to remote service ? ... why in My New Console Application is work ? and in Xamarin Android it doesn't work ?

Comment: It is able. You can connect to online service through Android Emulator, but not local service directly. If you want to connect to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in Android Emulator you must write`10.0.2.2`. But in your case I don't know how to connect to `http://192.168.16.100/`

Comment: Thank you for the news; I am not using emulator; I'm using an Android Device (Huawey Phone ) usb conected. My problem is I cannot connect to a remote database. So tone  solution is to connect to a WebService hosted on IIS (and this service will contains the queries against db);  In Xamarin tutorial they share this code: var uri = new Uri (string.Format (http://developer.xamarin.com:8081/api/todoitems{0}, string.Empty));   var response = await client.GetAsync (uri);
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    ..............
  }   But in my Android Aplication it doesn't connect;

Comment: Try to send get request to `http://cdn.crunchify.com/wp-content/uploads/code/json.sample.txt`.

Comment: Thank you so much; I think the problem is not connect because: my phone device is not connected to Internet ...let me check this and connect to the same network...(:

Comment: One thing. Are you sure that you've added permission to your app in order to connect to the internet?

Comment: Yes, thankyou so much!! now my phone device has Internet (I turned on WI-FI)...now the request is succesfully!!!!! thank you in advance !!

Comment: ....you have right;  cannot connect anymore ; no is not connect again; I don't understand why ...but how to set permissions to my app ?

Comment: See [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/)

Comment: I hope the solution is here: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/)?

For me it works great as a selfhosted wcf service. (Make sure that you run the selfhoster as Admin, otherwise it will fail)

You will need to download: [SlSvcUtil](https://www.microsoft.com/de-DE/download/details.aspx?id=28359) to create your app client and include it in your xamarin project.

Comment: Thank you; was the internet connection of my Android Phone close; I was turn on the WIFI and was able to connect; but now I have Internet on my phone but it doesn't work anymore....I think is need to set some permission for my phone in order to connect.....how to set permission for my Android application to connect to internet ?

Comment: add the following to your AndroisManifest.xml file:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> If you want to check if Wifi available or networkstate b4 you connect to the service you have to add 2 more permissions.